# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: str

Tags: python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta  
hours = input("Number of hours:") 

time = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=hours)
print(time)
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/uruma/Desktop/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    time = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=hour)
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta hours component: str
```

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

hours = 4
time = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=hours)
print(time)
____________________________
2020-10-28 06:00:30.149767
```

What I'm trying to do here is ask the user for the number of hours in order to calculate what hour will be after a certain amount of time, but I get an error. But if instead of the "input" code you put a number ... How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the value from `input()` is `string`.

Convert the input string into `int`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta  
hours = int(input("Number of hours:"))

time = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=hours)
print(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the user input to an integer before using it. Python input is a string by default.

> hours = int(input('Enter the number of hours: '))